# hector_mapping_parameters

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I used hector_mapping with a simulated robot. Firstly, I used the default values for all parameters specified on the ROS website http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping for hector_mapping.
But now, I would like to tune these parameters and I don't understand what the map_multi_res_levels parameter is supposed to do ?

If anyone could help me, I will be grateful.

lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234135/hector_mapping_parameters/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The slam present in the hector package use multiple maps for position estimation. Theses maps each have different resolution (divided by 2 I think).
So, if you have a resolution of 0.01, and map_multi_res_levels = 3, you will have :

- a map with resolution of 0.01
- a map with resolution of 0.02
- a map with resolution of 0.04

The algorithme will use these 3 maps to compute the best position estimation.

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-11**:
Ah ok, thank you for your quick and concise answer. I understand now.